# Xtext Content assist configuration

Tags: java, dsl, xtext, xtend

I want that the content assist suggests the name of variables already declared in the script. this is the grammar:

```
Script:
    includes+=(Include)* assignments+=(Assignment)* g=GetLog?  clock=Clock? tests+=Test*
;

Include:
    'INCLUDE' includedScript=[Script|STRING]
;

Test:
    'RUN'  "(" name=STRING "," com=STRING "," association=STRING ")" '{' instructions+=Instruction* '}'
;
    
Instruction:
    Set |
    Get |
    Verify |
    Execute |
    Wait |
    Print |
    Time |
    SetTime |
    PowerDown |
    PowerUp |
    GetIp |
    GetLog




Set:
    'SET' '(' attribute=AttributeRef ',' value=(AttributeValue ) ')'
;

Get : 

    'GET' '(' attribute=AttributeRef ')'
;
AttributeRef:
    cosem=IDValue "." attributeRef =IDValue

;
```

the `cosem` in `AttributeRef` part is which has to be already declared before.

for example, in this script when taping Tariffication the content assist shows TarifficationScriptTable

```
TarifficationScriptTable = COSEM(9,0,"0.0.10.0.100.255")



RUN("CheckConnectivity", "HDLC", "LOCAL_MANAGEMENT") {  

GET(Tariffi
```

Comment: How does your attribute ref look like? If you make proper use of cross references and implemented scoping accordingly (depending on your use case ) this will work out of the box

Comment: i have added it to the code

Comment: Why not using cross references ?

Comment: because i dont' know how

Comment: I recommend you to make familiar with cross references

Comment: I will try.  I struggle founding xtext documentation that is clear, simple and that I can understand

Comment: Did you read Lorenzo Bettinis book? Did you do the tutorials?

Comment: yes I did but not all of them.

Comment: and what do I add after doing the cross reference ?

Comment: you implement scoping for the cross references. unfortunately your example grammar shows to much and to few for that. what is a cosem and where does attributeRef point to ?!?

Comment: I have done it with crosse referencing and the content assist works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is what cross references are made for. you use them for scripts already. they look like

```
nameOfTheReference=[TypeYouWantToReference]
```

which is actually is a short for for

```
nameOfTheReference=[TypeYouWantToReference|ID]
```

which means "reference a TypeYouWantToReferenceand parse an ID"

if you have another rule that should be parsed you may use

```
nameOfTheReference=[TypeYouWantToReference|OtherRULE]
```